# code mirror html not working in chrome but working in other browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, codemirror

having some issue with Codemirror in chrome. it was working fine before but now its not working properly. the JavaScript code  still works but not the html. please have a look. [click here](http://singeek.com/sourcecodes/preview.php?sourceFor=test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you are missing `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration

Answer (score 3):

I seem to be facing the same issue with a NextJS (13) app. Somehow Chrome gives me the next error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'CodeMirror')

It happens with every entry/event to any input field in my app and until yesterday i didn't have any issues. I haven't made any changes to my code that could have had an effect on these input fields. Safari and Firefox don't give me any errors.

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="title"
    defaultValue={post.title}
    onChange={(e) => 
    setTitle(e.target.value)}
    placeholder="title"
/>
```

In my deployment on Vercel the input fields work perfect in Chrome. So it's localhost/Chrome issue.

**update**:

My issue was fixed by deleting the Blackbox extension from Chrome.